# How to reload a PHP page twice before displaying it completely to a user?

Tags: php

When a user opens a php page, can I make the page to reload by itself for two times before showing the contents of it to the user?

I tried to use:

```
header("Location: http://url");
```

but it goes on loop and never loads the page.

Comment: But why????????

Comment: i m displaying a mysql table data on a page and also doing some calculations on the datas fetched and trying to display it on the same page..

Comment: While what you're describing is possible, there really should be a better way to do this. Could you move the processing to an include file?

Comment: @raphael75 Or better still move this to an AJAX call from the page. No need to fiddle with redirects

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve. No matter what you want to do loading the same page thrice is not a good idea. If there's no alternative then at least consider using 3 different pages (pop-up ad style)

Comment: This sounds like a terrible solution. Why don't you just describe the problem you're trying to solve, and somebody can probably give you a better solution than "refresh the page twice"...

Comment: @Jyotishmoy why don't you fetch the mysql table data in your application (in your server side code, whatever language you're using) and perform the computations before rendering the page? Theres no reason to do what you're asking.

Comment: @Charles thanks, i just added one more page before the user goes to the page he wants and it worked..

Answer (score 1):

This is veeeery unusual, what I could think of is:

URL: page.php

```
if (!isset($_GET["time"]) && !isset($_GET["done"]))
{
    header("Location: http://url.com/page.php?time=1");
    exit;
}
else if ($_GET["time"] == 1)
{
    header("Location: http://url.com/page.php?time=2");
    exit;
}
else if ($_GET["time"] == 2)
{
    header("Location: http://url.com/page.php?done=1");
    exit;
}
```

Or you could use sessions, but good luck with that.

Comment: i m new to php.. so can u please say where should i add the portion of code in my page?

Comment: @Jyotishmoy, I'd say the beginning of the page. If none of the conditions match, do the rest of your code.

Comment: But what you're applying is a terrible experience for the user. You'll learn from this, but there are better ways.

Comment: can i do the same with javascript?